# How to Display Image Caption but Not Alt Text

Tags: images, post-meta, post-thumbnails, captions

I'm trying to display images with their caption, but when I do it displays both the caption and that alt text. I've tried to use `unset( $fields['image_alt'] );` to hide the alt text, but it does nothing. Here's my code:

```
                    <?php if (the_post_thumbnail_caption()) { 
                         the_post_thumbnail_caption();                          
                        } 

                        function remove_alt( $fields ) {
                            unset( $fields['image_alt'] );
                            return $fields;
                        }
                        add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'remove_alt', 999, 1 );
                    ?>
```

It first gets the caption, if there is one, and then the function is supposed to remove the alt text and keep the caption, but it's not working. Any suggestions for how to get this to work? Thanks so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```php
echo wp_get_attachment_caption(get_post_thumbnail_id());
```

Comment: Hey jxxe, thanks for the response. This actually does the same thing as the if statement at the beginning of my code. I'm trying to display the caption without the alt text.

Comment: I'm confused, because both my solution and `the_post_thumbnail_caption()` return just the caption for me: https://i.imgur.com/ycpn8eA.png. The post I tested it on has a featured image with a caption and alt text.